# Meaning of indices for cubic hermite splines

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

While digging through some code about Perlin noise, I noticed, that a Cubic Hermite Interpolation polynome is used at some point. At this point, I wanted to know, which of the Hermite basis polynomials ($h_{00}$, $h_{10}$, $h_{01}$ or $h_{11}$) it is.

$$
h_{??}(t) = 3 t^2 - 2t^3
$$

The actual problem is, that I took a look to the [german](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubisch_Hermitescher_Spline#Darstellungen_und_Verwandtschaft) and [english](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Representations) wikipedia to read about this topic. Unfortunately, the german wikipedia tells me that

$$
h_{01} = t^3 - 2t^2 + t \\
h_{10} = 3t^2 - 2t^3
$$

while the english wikipedia swaps the indices

$$
h_{01} = 3t^2 - 2t^3 \\
h_{10} = t^3 - 2t^2 + t
$$

I'd like to know, what the correct indices should be, and if they have a meaning.

Comment: The indices denote 1) the endpoint of the $[0,1]$ interval that contributes to the sum, 2) the order of the contribution (value or slope). If it were for me, I would probably use something like $v_0/v_1/s_0/s_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbols have no universal meaning, and different authors give different names to these four polynomials. The thing that distinguishes one of these polynomials from another is its "cardinality" properties: where the polynomial and its first derivative takes the values $0$ and $1$.

For the particular one you asked about, $h(t) = 3t^2 - 2t^3$, the important cardinality property is:
$$
h(0) = 0 \quad ; \quad h(1)=1 \quad ; \quad h'(0)=0 \quad ; \quad h'(1) = 0
$$